# Android - How to structure a layout that has two dynamic texts and then a list

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a screen where I get two items from SharedPreferences and display them to the screen, and then display a list via an adapter.

What I am not sure about is how to structure the layout xml file for this.  Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want? What are these "items"? Are they just displayed as a string each? Do you want each of these on a single line and the list below it? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the main layout with a listview. Then you can have a sub layout for each row of your list. This row layout, let's call it row_layout.xml may have two text areas if your items are text or it may have a text area and a checkbox button if that's what you want. Basically, whatever you want to display in a single row of your list.

Read up a tutorial, here's one:  http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), you can also create a view only listitem and add these item as header to the list

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean. Are you asking for examples of layouts with two textviews that can be updated via sharedprefs, with a ListView in the activity? Or just suggestions? An easy way to get started would be to use the Eclipse Android plugin that has a layout designer in it. Here is a tutorial on how to use it http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/ Its pretty easy and straight forward.